# Why is this third div affecting the other two divs?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div table and I'm getting annoying results.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.table-header {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #646464;
}
.table-cell {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.short-cell {
  height: 25px;
}
.col1 {
  width: 15%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.col2 {
  width: 35%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.col3 {
  width: 48%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.response {
  border-width: 2px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 98%;
  border-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-header col1">Question #</div>
<div class="table-header col2">Question</div>
<div class="table-header col3">Response</div>
<div class="table-cell col1 short-cell">1</div>
<div class="table-cell col2 short-cell">Question goes here</div>
<div class="table-cell col3 short-cell">
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a1cqr152/)

Before adding the final div in my code sample (the far bottom right cell), things look pretty good:

[image: Without final cell]

But as soon as I add the final cell, the previous two cells are moved down and I can't figure out why.

[image: With final cell, note first two columns displacement]

I'm running the latest stable Chrome (41).

What's causing this movement and how can I fix it so that the 3 table divs (and eventually more rows) are displayed in a proper row?

Comment: Not sure on the cause, but adding content (such as `&nbsp;`) fixes the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/a1cqr152/1/

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a table for this tabular data?

Comment: @isherwood The company I'm working for has a framework that they make all of their products with. That framework doesn't do tables. The divs are actually generated by the framework and all I can do is write the CSS and attach the classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**10.8 Line height calculations: the 'line-height' and 'vertical-align' properties**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height)
>
> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

Therefore you need to change the `vertical-align` property of the `.table-cell` elements to something other than the default value `baseline`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/58Lp8k0j/)

```
.table-cell {
    background-color: yellow;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

---

Without changing the `vertical-align` property, notice that the issue is resolved when adding text to the `.col3` element. [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/5ekz5f1L/)

Likewise, if you remove the text from all the elements, the issue is also resolved. [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/fvn6oyw5/)

This is because the last `.col3` element *was* being aligned to the baseline of the last line box in the normal flow (as the spec above states).

Comment: I never would have expected this. Thanks, it works like a charm.